# Create a class that is accessible to the whole application

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

In android there is a mechanism of ensuring that only one instance of a class is available to the whole application. This can be done by deriving that class from Application. 
Can some thing similar be done in servlets? I want to initialize a class when the application is deployed. This class should have only one instance. So that what all the servlets can access it. 
I came to know that you can store your data in the servlet context's hashmap. But I don't want to do that. I want to write my own class with its functions. How should this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're after is simply a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

This is best implemented by defining an enum with a single instance. (Note that enums allow you to have member functions just as classes.)

```
public enum YourSingleton {

    INSTANCE;

    // Your methods...

}
```

and then you access it as

```
YourSingleton.INSTANCE
```

Comment: This probably works, yeah, since a web app is almost certainly all within one `ClassLoader`. Using the `ServletContext` is a bit cleaner and stands a chance of being able to share the object across clustered instances, which may be desirable.

Answer (score 4):

So, create whatever class you want with its own functions or whatever you like, and put that in the `ServletContext` at startup.  You can use a `ServletContextListener` to initialize and remove it. What's limiting about that?

Comment: Will the object be serialized once the server shutsdown. I want to be able to continue with the object from the previous state.

Comment: No but you can easily persist and restore yourself in this listener.

Answer (score 1):

Use `singleton pattern` so the first call to instance method (say `YourClass.getInstance()`) will create the instance and it will be reused across the application.

Comment: In Java singletons are best implemented using enum.